# Calculating nearest places using Mysql GIS features

Tags: mysql, database, gis

We have 2 tables which store trip requests one for customer and one from driver. We have to show the nearest drivers to the customers and nearest customers to the drivers using MYSQL 5.7 GIS feature.

Both the tables store latitude and longitude of the requests. 
So if a driver requests for a trip I want to calculate distances and show the nearest customers in 10km radius and their locations to the driver from the customer request table.

I tried the `st_distance_sphere` which works good for `(Point,Point)`.
But if I pass in a `multipoint` and a `point` it returns zero.

**Shoudn't `multipoint,point` return distances between all points in first place to the point in 2nd place?**

Please correct if I am wrong.The query I tried is below.

```
SELECT 
  round(
    st_distance_sphere(
      st_geomfromtext(
        'Multipoint(72.87765590000004 17.385044,73.8567436 18.5204303)'
      ), 
      st_geomfromtext(
         'POINT (73.8567436 18.5204303)'
      )
    )
  ) as dist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the closest distance between the two geometries. In your multipoint you have

```
Multipoint(72.87765590000004 17.385044,73.8567436 18.5204303)
```

The second set of points here are exactly the as

```
POINT (73.8567436 18.5204303)'
```

So a distance of 0 is the correct response.

If you want to find the distance of a given point to multiple different points, you would need to have them as separate records in the table and have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  round(
    st_distance_sphere(some_point-field, 
      st_geomfromtext(
         'POINT (73.8567436 18.5204303)'
      )
    )
  ) as dist;
```

Comment: I assumed it returns distances to all points. How could I get distances to all points? I mean any function that is available?

Comment: yes, the above query will do it (with some_point_field being the last known location of each taxi (exists as rows in the table)). You might also want to see ST_Within

Comment: I already have them as different records.So you suggest I will have to loop through, is it?

Comment: once you execute that query, yes, you can loop through it in your program

Comment: `st_within` returns 0 or 1  based on the lat long. Can we pass in the radius by anyway? like mongo has something called as nearby or so? So I get results within a specific radius?

Comment: exactlly the way you are supposed to use it. You need to build a circle with the center at the clients point and pass it to dwithin.

Comment: But now we are getting way beyond the original scope of the question. May I suggest posting a new question to avoid making this one into one of those Chameleon questions.

Comment: I get your point.I guess I will have to use `st_distance_sphere` and `st_within` in co-ordination to achieve it. Thank you for the answer and help.

Comment: One more thing.Please explore postgis. It has a function called ST_DWithin which rocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120492/discussion-between-coderunner-and-e4c5).